# how to remove toolbar during onload function?

Tags: javascript

I have got one critical problem in Javascript; please help me to fix it.

I have written the onload function in one JSP page, say login.jsp.

In that function I used the window.open method to open a new window again with the same JSP page login.jsp with the toolbars disabled.

Now what is happening is that when I am opening the same page again in a new window, obviously that body onload function will get called again and it opens a new window in an indefinite loop.

But what I want is, I have to remove that onload function in that JSP page once a new window is opened.

Is it possible to remove that onload function while it is getting opened in the new window?

Could anyone please come up with an idea or little bit of code to do this using java script??

Comment: The actual question doesn't match the title.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onload`, check if the [`window.opener` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) is null.

If yes, open the new window.